# Is a large number of attributes in AngularJS indicative of an issue?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, coding-style

A general consensus is that, unless there are strong reasons to do otherwise, the number of parameters of a method should be *small enough*.

How much is *small enough* varies from author to author (seven for Steve McConnell in *Code Complete*, three for Robert C. Martin in *Clean Code*); I would suppose that most developers would agree that if most methods in a class contain five parameters or more, or if a given method contains more than ten parameters, further investigation is required.

Does this guideline apply to AngularJS attributes? By attributes, I mean `hello` and `something` in:

```
<my-component hello="world" something="abc" ...></my-component>
```

A practical case is that I'm reviewing a project where there are a bunch of AngularJS components and directives which contain eight to ten attributes, and some contain up to fifteen. If those were methods, I would raise an alert. However, I'm uncertain about the specificity of AngularJS, which could justify having a very flat structure instead of grouping attributes which belong together into separate objects.

I suppose that one of the reasons *not* to group attributes is to be able to define the attribute style (one way, etc.) in a more granular way.

Comment: parameter in a function/method and binding in angular are 2 different thing. binding binds variable of the class to a view and make a event propagation on change in view and same when change in model. so its kind of confusing what do you wnat

Comment: @AniruddhaDas: I wasn't talking about the bindings between a controller and a view, but about bindings used to pass information to a component or a directive. I explained what I mean by bindings by adding an example to my question.

Comment: you should call this attribute as angular compoenents are special html tags rather binding as binding have a special meaning in angular/angularjs

Comment: @AniruddhaDas: fixed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that html doesn't have limits to attributes nor angularjs has on bindings, it wouldn't be an issue because of number of bindings.

However, it can be an issue in terms of design at least, it's very dependent on each case. Perhaps you are talking about a *Dumb Component*, say [`ui-gmap-google-map` directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/demo) which could have like plenty of bindings, for example:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map
    center="map.center"
    zoom="map.zoom"
    dragging="map.dragging"
    bounds="map.bounds"
    events="map.events"
    options="map.options"
    pan="true"
    control="map.control">
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

In this case is totally acceptable and normal to use such approach even though it has alternatives like child components and transclusion areas for example.

However if you are talking about a *Smart Component*, say a Page Component Directive, having too many bindings on it, it looks like the component is not so smart and it's dependent on too many bindings to live.

> **Note on Bindings:** As per you've exemplified the function arguments case, for the bindings applies the same rule, to keep the function more responsible and as pure you can make it. Components on the other hand is required to have it's responsibilities solid and single, so the bindings are the arguments it require to do its responsibility.
>
> Therefore, a large amount of bindings (or arguments) can be a sign of a not so responsible component, but it's not the binding number that is the issue, is the garbage designed component;

Answer (score 1):

I would say there should not be any limit on how may attribute need to passed from the view to the component class.

#### should we call it binding to attribute

I would say you should call this attribute as its a html syntax and we pass data to the component class by binding special variable to this attribute.

More over these attribute values are not passed as function para meter rather a variables in the class.

#### html attributes

HTML attributes cannot be limited to 5 or 10. you can give number of attribute as per your requirement in the UI. Some people says angular components are new tags ang html 6 or something

#### Example of angular [2/4]

Here I passed 2 values to my child component by adding two attribute

If you will I normal case I should be allowed to bind as many as I want

In my class I have just variables to handle that.

```
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() text: string;
  @Output() editDone = new EventEmitter<Object>();
  private originalText: string;
```

Hope it helps.